# Нюансы работы с компонентом WindowsMediaPlayer

Tags: c#, winforms

При работе с компонентом WindowsMedaiPlayer столкнулся со странной особенностью: мне нужно чтобы при одиночном клике по компоненту он разворачивался на полный экран и при повторном клике он сворачивался в прежнее положение. Так вот, когда я в первый раз кликаю, то событие срабатывает, а когда кликаю второй раз - событие на клик не обрабатывается. Привожу код:

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flag_video == 0)
    {
        if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = true;
        }
        flag_video = 1;
    }
    else if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = false;
        flag_video = 0;
    }
}
```

Как можно исправить?

P.S. На обработку события на клик я вешал и просто вывод сообщения - все равно при повторном клике событие не обрабатывается.

Comment: Давно решил для себя, что такие задачи лучше решать через хуки мыши.
UPD:
Посмотрел [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562388(v=vs.85).aspx) и это не Ваш случай. У контрола есть MouseDown (Происходит при нажатии кнопки мыши.) Его и стоит использовать.

Comment: Это как? Можете пояснить на конкретном примере, что Вы имеет ввиду?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему вы говорите про клик на компоненте, а сами в коде демонстрируете событие Enter? Если нормально вешать клик, то все прекрасно работает. И да, ваш код можно сократить до двух строк.

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_MouseDownEvent(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MouseDownEvent e)
{
    if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = !axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen;
}
```

P.S. Только все равно вы забиваете данным решением функциональность плеера, так как невозможно будет щелкать по кнопкам плеера. Чем вас не устроил стандартный функционал на далб клик?

Comment: Огромнейшее Вам спасибо за помощь. Дело в том, что эта фича будет использоваться на сенсорной панели, а двойной клик, который предоставляют стандартные средства, будет плохо обрабатываться из-за качества экрана. Но в идеале, конечно, хотелось бы, чтобы функционал не забивался и можно было пользоваться панелью управлением видео.